# Easiest way to parse a Javascript date in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime, json.net

I see that JSON.NET has a DateTime converter:

```
string javascriptJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(entry, new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
```

However I don't have a JSON object, I simply have a string:

```
/Date(1276146000000-0500)/
```

I could create an object, add the date, then parse it, but this seems common enough that there should be a way to do this in a single line. Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes around the date string are required. Also, the returned value is a `DateTime`, not a `string`.

```
DateTime date =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>("\"/Date(1276146000000-0500)/\"");
```

Comment: Perfect! I had a really ugly Regex taking out the numbers, adjusting for local time and then doing adding the number to the epoch time!

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work:

```
DateTime date = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(
    "/Date(1276146000000-0500)/", new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion about this:  http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/18/dates-and-json.aspx

Just be sure to read all the comments which contain some good information.